# how to call class parameter inside the for loop?

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, rest, iterator

Problem:Cannot call the class parameter inside the for loop statement

Implementation:I need to call this class inorder my rest api list will function and will show all the data.

Problem:Cannot call the class parameter inside the for loop statement

Implementation:I need to call this class inorder my rest api list will function and will show all the data.

```
//this is working and able to get all the data, which the output is in "cmd";

public void ool8(){

     Product pBuilder = Product.newBuilder().build();
    ProductList productList =   productServiceBlockingStub.findAllRepeated(pBuilder);
     List<Product> products2 = productList.getProductList();
    
 
        for (Iterator iterator = products2.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Product product = (Product) iterator.next();
            
             ProductEntity productEntity2 = new ProductEntity(
                     product.getPurchaseItem(),
                     product.getProductname(),
                     product.getProductbrand(),
                     product.getProductprice(),
                     product.getProductdescription(),
                     product.getProductquantity(),
                     product.getProductexpirationdate()
                     );

             List<ProductEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
                
             list.add(productEntity2);
             
             System.out.println(list);
            
        }
```

```
//this is Not working cannot call the "productEntity2" outside the for loop;
//I need return in  a method List<ProductEntity> for rest api implementation.

public List<ProductEntity> ool8(){
    
    List<ProductEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
     Product pBuilder = Product.newBuilder().build();
    ProductList productList =   productServiceBlockingStub.findAllRepeated(pBuilder);
     List<Product> products2 = productList.getProductList();
    
 
        for (Iterator iterator = products2.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Product product = (Product) iterator.next();
            
             ProductEntity productEntity2 = new ProductEntity(
                     product.getPurchaseItem(),
                     product.getProductname(),
                     product.getProductbrand(),
                     product.getProductprice(),
                     product.getProductdescription(),
                     product.getProductquantity(),
                     product.getProductexpirationdate()
                     );

        }
    
    
        //this is the issue calling "productEntity2" outside of for loop
         list.add(productEntity2);
         
         System.out.println(list);
         
         return list;

        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`productEntity2` lives in the [scope](https://www.codecademy.com/article/variable-scope-in-java) of the `for` loop, you created it there. Hence, you cannot call `productEntity2` outside of the loop (its scope). It looks to me that for each product in `iterator`, you'd like to add an entity to `list`, so the right thing to do is putting `list.add(productEntity2);` inside the for loop (at the end, right after creating `productEntity2`).